# Full Calendar header not aligning elements properly

Tags: button, alignment, fullcalendar

I'm trying to align the "today", "<", and ">" buttons on my calendar to the right. However, It's not behaving the way I expect it to despite providing the header property with an object containing the settings I'd like. Here's how my code looks like for rendering the calendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      events: '/api/shifts',
      eventBackgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
      eventBorderColor: '#f2f2f2',
      height: 400,
      contentHeight: "auto",
      header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: 'today prev next'
      }
    });
```

Here's how it looks like when I view it on the browser.

[image: screenshot of result]

How can I get it to align to the right properly?

Comment: Looks ok to me using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/215/ . Are you sure you haven't messed with the CSS somehow? Can you make a runnable example (e.g. using JSFiddle) which reproduces your issue so we can investigate?

Comment: I will need to get back to you on this. However, it's interesting that you have it working by using CDNs. One issue I'm having with posting it on jsfiddle is getting it to work as most of the files I include locally on my development machine, which I cannot link to. I'm currently using version 3.8.2 (not that I think it matters). I tried direct linking to CDNs, but the calendar would not show up at all. I'm not sure what's happening. I'm also using jquery instead of jquery-ui.

Comment: I'm not using jQueryUI either. It was only there because I re-used an old fiddle. See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/217/ - I removed it and it's still fine. I would guess you have some CSS of your own which is interfering. Try inspecting the elements in your browser tools to see if something is overwriting the fullCalendar rules. And/or try removing your custom CSS from your page until it works properly, and then you'll have a clue to the source of the error.